# Find which option is selected

Tags: xpath

I have this piece of code:

```
<select id="customizableonly" class=" select" name="product[customizableonly]">
   <option value="1">Yes</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="0">No</option>
</select>
```

And I need an `xpath` string that will find this `<select id="customizableonly"...>` tag and see which of its 2 options has the attribute `selected="selected"`. Therefore, return the value of the "selected" option (*Yes* or *No*). If someone can give a quick solution - I'd appreciate that a lot!

I've got this far `//select[@id='customizable']` for acquiring the main tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right, all you have to do is

```
//select[@id='customizableonly']/option[@selected='selected']/text()
```